# Dryer circuit box is still showing active

Tags: circuit-breaker, dryer, circuit

The circuit box for my dryer has been tripping recently. It gives a fishy type of smell. I bought a new 30 amp circuit from LOWES to replace it. When I turned the main power off to my home through the breaker box, the wire going into the dryer circuit box is showing on. How do I replace this circuit box?

Comment: Either you turned off the main breaker in a sub panel that the dryer is not connected to, or you have a big problem with the breaker and should have the power company turn off the power or you use the outside disconnect if you have one.  Are there breakers in the outside box with the meter and a panel inside the house?

Comment: There’s not enough information to answer this. How are you detecting a live circuit? When you talk about a “30 amp circuit from Lowe’s” are you talking about a circuit breaker that fits in your panel? Need photos of that and your panel. (And the old circuit breaker if you have it.)

Comment: Pleas be more specific about how you determined ..."the wire is on".  ( there are 2 hot leads to a dryer)   Is a "circuit box" a circuit breaker, or something else?  Where in the world are you?   'Lowes" indicates USA, but?  If the circuit breaker is tripping, it is probably doing it's job.  There may be another issue that it is protecting you from.

Comment: Please take a clear, legible picture of the label in your panel, the label of the old breaker, the label of the new breaker and the wiring as it currently stands, then [edit] those into your question (simply drag/drop the images in or click the sun & mountain icon). Something is very wrong here, but we really need more details to help you answer your question.

Comment: First, if you call it a "circuit box" you may need to step back - those terminals must be tightened with a torque screwdriver, and the correct breaker must be used. 3 other makes will "fit" and then burn up the stab.  Most likely you have a Rule of Six / Split-Bus panel, where up to 6 breakers together are the main breaker.  You cannot de-energize that bus.